# What's the meaning of the comma in a jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><strong>list</strong> item 1 -
    one strong tag</li>
  <li><strong>list</strong> item <strong>2</strong> -
    two <span>strong tags</span></li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
  <li>list item 6</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('li').filter(function(index) {
  return $('strong', this).length == 1;
}).css('background-color','red');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Given the HTML above, what's the meaning of the comma in the selector below?

```
return $('strong', this).length == 2;
```

What will happen if I remove the word 'strong'?

Comment: I know this is a really old question, but the title is misleading - the comma is not **in** the selector, it's in the argument list to the jQuery function.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It sets `this` as the context from which the query is performed.

An equivalent (and slightly more efficient) way to write it is:

```
return $(this).find('strong').length == 2;
```

When I say equivalent, I mean behind the scenes, it is actually flipped around into the version above.

If you remove the `'strong'`, you won't have a valid selector. You'll be doing:

```
return $(this).find('').length == 2;
```

Looks like it just returns an empty jQuery object, which means `length` will be `0`, so you won't get any elements out of the `.filter()`.

---

**Reference**:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

jQuery( selector [, context ] )

*context*

Type: Element or jQuery

A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context

Comment: how about this $("p").filter(".selected, :first"), what this mean?Thanks!!

Comment: A `.filter()` runs the selector you provide it against the set in the jQuery object, returning a new set with only those elements that match. In your example, `$('p')` will select all `<p>` elements in the document. `.filter(".selected, :first")` will reduce that set to those that have the `selected` class, and are the `:first` in the set. Because you're using `:first`, you'll only get one match (the first one in the set) and only if it has the `selected` class.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove STRONG tag, it would check if any of LI contain string 1 character long, regardless if they encapsulated within STRONG tag.
In this case no results would be highlighted.
Selectors like $('strong', this) and $(this).find('strong') are pretty much the same.

Comment: how about this $("p").filter(".selected, :first"), what this mean?Thanks!!

Comment: Patrick did good explanation on this subject, consider to accept his answer to close this question.