# what is this jQuery syntax and how is it useful?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Once I saw a jQuery selection using something like this

```
$(".myClass", $(this));
```

Have I got it correct and what exactly does it do?

I can probably just google it if I knew the name, but I don't know what it's called.

Comment: But what you want to select?

Comment: this is to provide context, `.find()` syntax is preferred

Comment: This was already answered [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543336/whats-the-meaning-of-comma-in-jquery-selector][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543336/whats-the-meaning-of-comma-in-jquery-selector

Comment: @blackops better title too. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It's the equivalent of using a `find` starting from `this`

```
$(this).find(".myClass");
```

The syntax for your example could also be shortened to just: `$(".myClass", this);` - no need to re-jQuery the `this`

Comment: Thanks. Where's the documentation on http://api.jquery.com/?

Comment: @thomas, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context