# How to store and reuse a combination of selector and context expressions in a single variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've recently come to enjoy using this pattern of JQuery selector that I suppose you could describe as a syntactical shortcut for the .find() API:

```
$('.some-element', '.within-context')
```

There's a discussion about it on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543336/whats-the-meaning-of-the-comma-in-a-jquery-selector)

Anyway, I find myself in the situation where I'd like to store this selector as a variable that I can use in multiple places in my script.

Obviously I can't do this: `var selector = '.some-element', '.within-context'` as that would just leave me with a variable holding `'.within-context'`

`'.some-element, .within-context'` is something entirely different...

And despite sleuthing around the docs and SO, I'm not even sure what this does: `$(['.some-element', '.within-context'])`

Not really sure what else to try, should I just make two variables?

Comment: `var $theElem = $('.some-element', '.within-context')` or may be you would like to use this way too.

Comment: @Nick I don't believe it's an XY question, because the OP has no underlying X problem to begin with. The question is indeed simply _how can this syntactic sugar be achieved?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to expand the `$`'s arguments from an array. This way you can store a selector combination in an array and pass it later on as two distinct arguments to the jQuery constructor.

For example:

```js
let someSelectorCombo = ['.some-element', '.some-context']; // Store the selector

$(...someSelectorCombo).text('Yay') // Expand the stored selector to two arguments
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="some-context">
    <div class="some-element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No. It will not. I just realized and modified my answer.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I believe it does, as I've tested.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Added a snippet to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `$('.within-context .some-element')`?

Or if you still wanna use context, you can use `apply`, but I see not much point

```
var selectorWithContext = ['.some-element', '.within-context'];
$.apply(null, selectorWithContext);
```