# Apex main region header with dynamic value

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have tried everything I know to make title of header replicate items value, including substitution string &P10_TITLE_TEXT. inside headers title property. Generally, this would work for normal region, but in my case I try to modify value of pages main region, which is rendering first, before any other item. My assumption is that title text is not showing because it cannot see items value yet.

Is there a simple way to refresh title header after items are ready, or perhaps another better solution?

PS: This is main header of the modal dialog page, that has no property for setting static id, and it's template is less adjustable then normal regions.

Comment: Does your question have anything to do with Salesforce? (Visualforce, Aura, Lightning Experience, Lightning Web Components)? If you mean Oracle's Application Express - retag it as "oracle-apex"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following javascript in "Execute When Page Loads" of the modal page:

```
$('.ui-dialog-title',parent ? parent.document : document).text( apex.items. P10_TITLE_TEXT.value );
```

Comment: I have no idea what this comma means. It made more sense when I seen it first time. Is this shorthand for javascript if statement?

Comment: Stackoverflow to the rescue ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543336/whats-the-meaning-of-the-comma-in-a-jquery-selector

Answer (score 1):

Pre-Rendering computations may be the solution here.

You can try creating a computation before Regions under **Pre-Rendering** to set `&P10_TITLE_TEXT.`. There will be no need to "refresh". This is if you are simply loading it once.

If you are trying to set headers based on input every time you change it, I would advise separating into two pages so you can ***submit*** the page and APEX can reload and process, or just use javascript.